# Show and hide bootstrap tooltip using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show bootstrap tooltip when user click on element and condition is false. I've written code for this:

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="You must to log in!" class="stars">425</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
$(".statistics .stars").click( function(){
    if (! user.isLogin){
        $(this).tooltip("show");

        setTimeout(function(){
          $(this).tooltip( 'hide' );
        }, 2000);   
    }
});
```

When I don't click I can see default tooltip on hover (I don't need it) and when I click, tooltip don't hide after 2 seconds. How to solve this problems?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you need to set tooltip to be manual, now it will not popup on hover

```
$('div').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'});
```

After that you need to save div element before using it inside setTimeout because `this` outside of setTimeout and `this` inside of setTimeout is different.

```
$('div').click(function(){
  var tt = $(this);
  if (! user.isLogin){
    tt.tooltip("show");

    setTimeout(function(){
      tt.tooltip( 'hide' );
    }, 2000);   
  }
});
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vstlu/2/)

Comment: For future reference I want to state that if {trigger: 'manual'} doesn't do the trick then data-trigger="manual" should do

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
$(".statistics .stars").click( function(){
    if (! user.isLogin){
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.tooltip("show");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $el.tooltip( 'hide' );
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```