# Android Remove Focus From Webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have webview content in my webview, it is like a graph;

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #graph {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #graph li {
            background: #19bafc;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 6px;
            width: calc(5% - 5.7px);
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        #graph li:first-child {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

        #graph .red-1 {
            background: #fbb75e;
        }

        #graph .red-2 {
            background: #fb8f76;
        }

        #graph .red-3 {
            background: #fa7252;
        }

        #graph li:hover {}

        #graph li .tooltip {
            background: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            top: calc(50% - 25px);
            left: calc(50% - 78px);
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        #graph li:hover .tooltip {
            display: block;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }

        #graph li .tooltip .date {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 6px;
            color: #97b8c6;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="graph">
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>100% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>99% Uptime</div></li>
            <li class="red-1"><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>13% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>98% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>97% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>95% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>98.34% Uptime</div></li>
            <li class="red-2"><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>56% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>34% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>45% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>55% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>100% Uptime</div></li>
            <li class="red-1"><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>34% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>67% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>45% Uptime</div></li>
            <li class="red-2"><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>23% Uptime</div></li>
            <li class="red-3"><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>45% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>35% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>56% Uptime</div></li>
            <li><div class="tooltip"><span class="date">05/03 15.20 / 05.03 15.34</span>76% Uptime</div></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using a webview;

```
    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/graph"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
graph.loadUrl(URL);
```

It is working just fine but my problem is this; when I touch a li on webview, tooltip is showing but even if I click something clickable like a Button or EditText, WebView is not losing hover and tooltip stucks.

I read everything about focus but I could not solve my problem.

Comment: I would suggest to check for a JavaScript solution mage something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37938714/944070 webview contents focus are not part of the rest of the android elements on screen

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question completely , You should handle focus lost in android and pass it to webview , so webview could be advised and lose focus from element.

To implement this , you should create a jQuery function in your webpage to clear the focus :

```
    function clear_focus()
{
 $( "body" ).focus();
}
```

Then wherever you click elements other than webview , for example an editbox . It should run this function to run JavaScript function in webview:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:clear_focus()");
```

Comment: Actually this wasn't solve my problem but you gave me an idea and I've applied it. So it's not the right answer but I'm giving upvote. I solve my problem by making my outer layout clickable and assigning an onclick event to it.